# tablesorter - How to sort child rows and parent rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablesorter

I'm using tablesorter on my project with the children functionality ([described here](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-child-rows.html)).

Here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('table').tablesorter();
});
```

```css
td,
th {
  border: solid 2px #121E23
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

thead {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>this is column 1</th>
        <th>this is column 2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="4">TITLE 1</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tablesorter-childRow">
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>yolo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tablesorter-childRow">
        <td>def</td>
        <td>yolo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="4">TITLE 2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tablesorter-childRow">
        <td>test1</td>
        <td>yolo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tablesorter-childRow">
        <td>test2</td>
        <td>yolo</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.31.1/js/jquery.tablesorter.combined.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

By default we have this:

[image: 1]

And if we change the sorting order of the first column (by clicking on it), we get this :

[image: 2]

Simply because tablesorter sorts the parent rows (TITLE 1 and TITLE 2), and keeps the children rows in the same order as at the beggining.
But I would like tablesorter to also sorts the children rows, and so to get my table like this:

[image: 3]

How can I do that ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: the docs you reference are to filter child columns not sort them.

Comment: @GifCo link seems correct to me, docs about filtering children is another link [here](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-child-rows-filtered.html)